# why the getline function isn't recognizing it as a string?

Tags: c++, memory-management, getline

There is a pointer struct named children, and within it there are these two pointers, name and age.

```
employees[i].children[j].name = new string();
employees[i].children[j].age = new int[1];
cout << "WRITE THE NAME OF THE DEPENDENT " << j+1 << endl;
getline(cin,employees[i].children[j].name);
```

This is giving me this error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istream&, std::string*&)’

Comment: It is nearly always a mistake to make a pointer for a singular thing that you are not intended to share. Most likely you should replace `string *name` and `int *age` with `string name` and `int age`, because you do not need another level of indirection there.

Comment: Because, according to your code sample, its not a `string`, its a *pointer* to a `string`. As others have said probably best to not make it a pointer. Use `string name;` rather than `string* name;`. Same for `age`. Then you get to not bother with the `name = new string();` part at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name` field is a pointer to a string. You need to use:

```
getline(cin,*(employees[i].children[j].name));
```

Comment: More likely `name` should be `std::string` and `age` should be `int` (based on the name; why would `age` be more than one `int`?)

Comment: It would probably make more sense for name to be a straight object, and I can't think of a reason age needs to be an array. However, I, personally, dislike when people second-guess how I write my code. Perhaps he is getting his data structures from a place where he cannot modify them (3rd party SW or a professor). I'm just answering the question he asked.

Comment: The way I see it, at best, the suggestions are helpful and you learn something. At worst, you know they don't apply and you lose a few seconds of your life reading them. This assumes that an answer for the original problem is actually given.

Comment: @chris You're absolutely right, when phrased as a suggestion (like yours was) I think comments like that can be tremendously helpful. I hope I wan't being too rude in my previous comment. I've just seen plenty of condescension on stackoverflow in the path.